# Does Android provide widget like the iPhone UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, android, uipickerview

I feeling that the UIPickerView of iPhone is good idea and easy to use on touchable mobile phone. I am strange that why Android SDK do not provide the same effect widget ?

or maybe coder have to clone it on Android ?

any help ... thanks ...

Answer (score 13):

FWIW, I was looking for the same thing, and I found this -> http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel.  I have not used it yet, but I am thinking about giving it a whirl.

Answer (score 5):

I think the [spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) would be the android equivalent.  It doesn't have the same eye candy, but functionally it would be the same.  You could write your own widget to add the eye candy and animations though.

Comment: Can you have multiple columns in the spinner though?  That's what makes the UIPickerView so powerful and is often used (date picking for example)...  how do Android apps do date picking?

Comment: There is a DatePicker Widget, although I have never used it.(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)

Comment: The spinner is totally different from uipickerview in that the spinner only displays one item at a time in its initial state. Only when you tap it, it displays the other options. It's different in many other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html). Although it has 3 visible fields instead of 7, and it doesn't have 3D effect (it is just a table with some fading out).