# Custom Picker View In android

Tags: android, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Android provide widget like the iPhone UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852374/does-android-provide-widget-like-the-iphone-uipickerview)

I am new to android. I want to know how to create something like pickerview in iphone. I need to load some text to it like list of countries. Please check the image. It will give a clear idea. Thanks in advance!

http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2157/pickerview.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[try this](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

Comment: Thank you very much ! this is what i was searching for.

Comment: mark the answer as correct if it serves your purpose